# Difference between eviction policies in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I'm going over the documentation for Hazelcast and I'm noticing the differences in eviction policies and I noticed one that I didn't fully understand.

```
map_size_per_jvm: Max map size per JVM.

partitions_wide_map_size: Partitions (default 271) wide max map size.
```

I'm assuming both of these are talking about entries and not size in terms of storage space. Isn't a partition going to rest on 1 JVM? To me this would see like these are the same option, can anyone help me make sense of the difference between these 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, yes, the max sizes `map_size_per_jvm`, `cluster_wide_map_size` and `partitions_wide_map_size` are per-entry (not size in terms of storage space).

Secondly, these *max sizes* are hard limits, and whilst similar they are in fact different to the *eviction policies* (being `LRU`, `LFU` or `NONE`).

Here's how they work:

1. **cluster_wide_map_size** - this is the total map entries across all hazelcast nodes.
2. **map_size_per_jvm** - this is essentially the number of map entries per hazelcast node.

   So if you are running 2 nodes using this policy with max size = 10 (and backupCount = 0, see below), you have max 20 map entries across all nodes. Adding another hazelcast node increases the total max map size.
3. **partitions_wide_map_size** - this one is a little unpredictable, since it depends on the distribution of partitions across your nodes.

   A cluster node reaches it's maximum when it reaches it's proportion of *(owned partitions / total partitions)* of the max size. Code: [MaxSizePartitionsWidePolicy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hazelcast/hazelcast/2.5/com/hazelcast/impl/CMap.java#CMap.MaxSizePartitionsWidePolicy)

Please **note** that all of these max sizes include *backups*, so `backupCount = 1` effectively reduces the real max map size in half.

The other max size settings, `used_heap_size` and `used_heap_percentage` seem clear in their usage.

I hope this helps, good luck!